# Perl one-liner Windows 10 / Power Shell : replace a string in multiple file ending by *.sql won't work (* globing not recognized)

Tags: windows, powershell, perl, glob

The following one-liner Perl statement didn't work when using the "*" globbing:

```
>>> perl -i'.bak' -pe 's#__SUB__CWD__#'$(pwd)'#g' *.sql
Can't open *.sql: Invalid argument.
```

The following statement works but only when you give a single file as an argument:

```
>>> perl -p -i'.bak' -e 's#__SUB__CWD__#'$(pwd)'#g' A_SINGLE_FILE.sql
```

Any idea what could make perl to realize "*" must be read in a REGEX way?

I'm trying to replace all the occurence of "**SUB__CWD**" in tons of files.

C.f. https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not Perl's fault, it's Windows' fault. Linux shells expand the wildcards for you, cmd.exe does not. I don't know about PowerShell, but it seems it doesn't either.

Also, you don't want to interpret the asterisk the regex way, but the glob pattern way. In a regex, `*` means "the previous thing should be repeated zero or more times".

You can use Perl's [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob) function:

```
perl -p -i'.bak' -e 'BEGIN {@ARGV = glob shift} s#__SUB__CWD__#'$(pwd)'#g' *.sql
```

Note that you need to backslash backslashes in the path to prevent Perl from interpreting them, i.e. use `$($pwd -replace '\\', '\\')` instead of just `$(pwd)`. You also need to backslash the `#` characters in the path as they would otherwise be understood as the delimiters, so use `$($pwd -replace '[\\#]', '\$&')`.

Therefore, it would be even cleaner not to use `$(pwd)`, but let Perl know what the replacement is:

```
perl -p -i'.bak' -e 'BEGIN{ ($pwd, @ARGV) = (shift, map glob, @ARGV) }
                   s/__SUB__CWD__/$pwd/g' -- $(pwd) *.sql
```

The first argument is assigned to `$pwd` via [shift](http://p3rl.org/shift), the remaining attributes are mapped to glob, which means you can specify more than one wildcard pattern.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer. That worked (with -i'.bak' instead of -i.bak ) . It's indeed a Powershell issue, which is the reason why I mentionned it in the Top Question so that other people find your answer. The command worked totally fine on Mac OSX.

Comment: Just another question: when do we use  of the hashtag # in "s#string#replacement_string#g" vs. the slash "/" in "s/string/replacement_string/g" ?

Comment: Thanks very much also for the precision on the distinction between the REGEX wildcard vs. GLOB wildcard. That was a very helpful!

Comment: @tmangin: You can use any delimiter you like. The slash is the standard one, a programmer usually switches to a different one if they need to use literal slashes in the regex or replacement, so they don't need to backslash them. Using `s{}{}` in such a case is recommended by the Perl Best Practices book.

Answer (score 3):

[choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61001681/45375) provides good pointers and solutions focused more on the `perl` side of things.

A **direct adaptation** of your command to **PowerShell *on Windows*** is (both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core]):

```
perl -i'.bak' -pe "s#__SUB__CWD__#$($pwd -replace '[\\#]', '\$&')#g" (Get-ChildItem *.sql).Name
```

As choroba points out, PowerShell *on Windows* does *not* do globbing (expansion of wildcard patterns to matching filenames) for you; however, it does on Unix-like platforms - see below.

- `(Get-ChildItem *.sql).Name` uses the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet to perform the globbing manually.
- `$pwd -replace '[\\#]', '\$&'` uses PowerShell's regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to ensure that both the `\` path separators in the current-directory path as well as any `#` characters are `\`-escaped, to ensure that `\` isn't interpreted as the start of an *escape sequence* by Perl `s` function, and that a `#` isn't misinterpreted as a delimiter character.

For **PowerShell [Core] *on Unix-like platforms* (macOS, Linux)**:

Essentially, your command would work *as-is* - as long as the current directory path doesn't contain spaces (which would affect your command in POSIX-like shells such as `bash` too).

The following variant addresses this problem:

```
# PowerShell [Core] on macOS and Linux
# If the current-directory path contains '#' chars.,
# use the -replace operation shown above.
perl -i'.bak' -pe "s#__SUB__CWD__#$(pwd)#g" *.sql
```

<sup>Note: `$($pwd)` would be slightly more efficient, because it uses the automatic `$PWD` *variable* rather than the `pwd` *command*, an alias for the `Get-Location` cmdlet.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. That Get-ChildItem command for PowerShell Windows is going to be very useful.